# One(state)-to-Many(emissions) Hidden Markov Model in Python

Tags: python, lstm, hidden-markov-models, hmmlearn

Is there a way to implement a Hidden Markov Model wherein a single state can emit multiple emission symbols (one[state]-to-many[emissions])?

[image]

For instance, suppose I have two states `states = {S1, S2}` and four emission symbols `symbols = {A, B, C, D}`. The Viterbi algorithm can be invoked to find the most likely path that generates an example emission `'ABCD'` - where it assumes that each state emitted exactly one symbol (ie. `S1 -> A, S2 -> B, S1 -> C, S1 -> D` .

What I would like to do is to expand the dimension of emissions symbols such that each state can emit multiple symbols `symbols = {A, B, C, D, AA, AB, AC, AD, BA, BB, BC, BD ...}`. In this way, the state path length may be different from the emission path length: (ie. `S1 -> AB, S2 -> C, S3 -> D // 3 states, 4 emitted symbols`). I know this one-to-many model is possible with LSTMs, is this possible with a classical HMM architecture?

Comment: Have you already seen this article? https://towardsdatascience.com/hidden-markov-model-implemented-from-scratch-72865bda430e

Comment: No; interesting link, but I am not asking how to implement a generic HMM.